# Sending object of a class from client to server using serialization

Tags: c++, sockets, serialization, client-server, deserialization

I  have two classes a client.cpp and a server.cpp using tcp sockets and message is sent from client side to server.
In client i have a class employee having different values as follows:

```
            class employee{
             int emp_id;
             char emp_name;
             float emp_weight;
             };
```

I have made the object of employee as:

```
             employee *ptr=new employee();
             ptr->emp_id=10;
             ptr->emp_weight=50.2;
             memcpy(ptr->emp_name,"MESSAGE",7);
```

Now passing  this data from client as:

```
             send(socket_connection,(char*)&ptr,sizeof(ptr),NULL);
```

On Server side i am recieving as:

```
             char *server_buffer=new char[256];
             recv(socket_connection,server_buffer,sizeof(employee),NULL);
             employee *pointer=(employee*) server_buffer;
             char b[256];
             memcpy(b,pointer->emp_name,sizeof(pointer->emp_name));
             cout <<  "Got data as "<< pointer->emp_name << "\n";
              cout <<  "Got data as "<< ptr->emp_id << "\n";
              cout <<  "Got data as "<< ptr->emp_weight << "\n";
```

My question is:

Why am i getting garbage values in my output and how to resolve it ?

Kindly help me to understand this.I am doing this activity for my understanding regarding serialization and deserialization.

Comment: It's generally not recommended to send raw structures across a TCP stream, unless you really know what you're doing, in terms of byte-order, packing/padding, etc. Also, recall that TCP is a *stream* - you may receive 1 byte or more.

Comment: Initaily i was simply passing integer value i.e emp_id and i created object as employee object; without using pointer and accesed emp_id as object.emp_id=10; the reciever did recived it and i got the same value in output also.But as i creeadted object by making pointer i get garbage value.So,why is it happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your employee class has only one character for the emp_name member. You cannot fit a string like "MESSAGE" into one character. Attempting to do so will copy the excess characters into the memory of emp_weight, creating garbage. You could fix this by declaring

```
char emp_name[128];
```

On the receive size it is mandatory that you check the return value from recv. You may get less bytes than you expect, and when that happens you must call recv again to get more bytes.